# populating tableview with multiple sections from only one NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, duplicates, tableview, sections

This here is the last update. It is crashing when setting texts in indexpath.section ==0 and ==1 and ==2 with the error

[Home objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x109624f20
2014-07-30 12:03:24.732 TYM-APP[1704:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Home objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x109624f20'

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath
{
NSLog(@"wsolna hon");
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"HomeTableViewCell";
HomeTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

// Configure the cell...
int row= [indexPath row];


                if (indexPath.section == 0){
                     homeObject = [homeArray[0] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

                         NSAttributedString * attrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[homeObject.News dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
                    cell.NewsDateLabel.text= homeObject.News_Date;
                    cell.NewsLabel.attributedText= attrStr;
                    NSLog(@"news: %@", attrStr);

                }


                if (indexPath.section == 1){
                    homeObject = [homeArray[1] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

                  NSLog(@"value of indexpath for library: %d",row);
                         NSLog(@"library: %@",homeObject.News);
                    cell.NewsLabel.text= homeObject.Library_text;
                    cell.TestimonialNameLabel.text= @"";

            }

                if (indexPath.section == 2){
                    homeObject = [homeArray[2] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

                         NSLog(@"news: %@",homeObject.Testimonial_Description);
                    cell.NewsLabel.text= homeObject.Library_text;
                    cell.TestimonialNameLabel.text = homeObject.Testimonial_Name;

            }


return cell;
}
```

Comment: Don't query the database every time you are asked for a cell. Query once and cache the results. Log the results array. How many duplicate objects and modules are there?

Comment: the first section is being diplayed properly but is being duplicated in every other section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the quantity of sections is fixed, I would recommend you to store your data in multidimensional array. Thus it will protect you from the most of logical mistakes later.

```
// Declaring array for 3 sections
homeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init], [[NSMutableArray alloc] init], [[NSMutableArray alloc] init], nil];
```

Then perform necessary logical separation during retrieving data and placing it into array

**UPDATE:** As @Wain said, it's not recommended to do any requests inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, so it will be better to place next snippet in that place where you are caching your information

```
if ([moduleID isEqualToString:@"77"]){
    [homeArray[0] addObject:[[Home alloc]initWithItemID: modID andNewsName:nText andNewsDate: (NSString *) nDate andLibraryText: dText andTestDescription: tText andTestimonialName: (NSString *) tName]];
} else if ([moduleID isEqualToString:@"81"]){
    [homeArray[1] addObject:[[Home alloc]initWithItemID: modID andNewsName:nText andNewsDate: (NSString *) nDate andLibraryText: dText andTestDescription: tText andTestimonialName: (NSString *) tName]];
} else if ([moduleID isEqualToString:@"78"]){
    [homeArray[2] addObject:[[Home alloc]initWithItemID: modID andNewsName:nText andNewsDate: (NSString *) nDate andLibraryText: dText andTestDescription: tText andTestimonialName: (NSString *) tName]];
}
```

And, finally, get necessary homeObject for your table this way

```
if (indexPath.section == 0) {
    homeObject = [homeArray[0] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
} else if (indexPath.section == 1) {
    homeObject = [homeArray[1] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
} else if (indexPath.section == 2) {
    homeObject = [homeArray[2] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

Comment: i am getting this error : index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
can i edit my question to the new code to show you the code if you don't mind?

Comment: @ralph sure, no problems. Where exactly did you get this error?

Comment: @ralph You forgot to update array initialization, it's not 2-dimensional now.
Change homeArray = `[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];` to `homeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init], [[NSMutableArray alloc] init], [[NSMutableArray alloc] init], nil];
`

Comment: ok now i have this problem: Home objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10926eca0
2014-07-30 11:01:51.337 TYM-APP[1419:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Home objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10926eca0'

Comment: i think it is at this line: homeObject = [homeArray[0] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Comment: anyways thank you @vlad24. :) i'll try to fix it now

Comment: @ralph This means that you are trying to get element from non-array object, but from your `homeObject`, which is not an array. Check your code again, may be you missed index and assigned `homeObject` to `homeArray`.

Comment: i think it's working now but it's crashing when setting texts to labels. can you check it please? and it's the last time i bother you hehe

Comment: @ralph The code you've presented looks ok, this kind of error can't occur during regular NSString objects assignment. So I can't actually tell you what's the problem. It is either an issue in your Home class implementation or wrong sending of objectAtIndex: message to homeObject somewhere in your code. I think you should create another question since it's already another kind of problem.

Comment: this issue is at this line: HomeTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];    the app crashes at this line when i scroll down

Comment: sorry the crash is from this line after scrolling:  homeObject = [homeArray[0] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Answer (score 0):

This is a cell reuse problem.

To fix, ensure that each time you return a cell from cellForRowAtIndexPath: you always set the text label contents for all labels. That means explicitly setting some with text and setting the others to have no text.

The alternative (and cleaner) solution is to use different custom cells for each section.

Also, don't query the database every time you are asked for a cell. Query once and cache the results. It's very wasteful to query each time and will make your app run slower.